# TcpSockets do not connect

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to establish a TCP connection between a laptop as a client and a pc as a server.
My goal is to use the server to send messages between two android devices. The server has a public IP address. To test the connection, I have written two simple Java classes:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpServer {    
    public ServerSocket welcome;
    public Socket soc;
    public int listeningPort = /* default port */;

    public TcpServer() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TcpServer ms = new TcpServer();
        if(args.length > 0) {
            ms.listeningPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        ms.listen();
    }

    public void listen() {
        try {
            welcome = new ServerSocket(listeningPort);
            System.out.println(">>> listening on port " + listeningPort + " <<<");

            soc = welcome.accept();
            System.out.println(">>> got a new connection from "
                    + soc.getInetAddress().toString() + " <<<");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
                    soc.getInputStream().read(b, 0, 1);
                    System.out.print((char) (b[0]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }       
    }
}

import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpSendClient {    
    private String serverIp = /* some ip */;
    public int port = /* default port */;
    private SendThread st;

    public TcpSendClient() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TcpSendClient client = new TcpSendClient();
        if(args.length > 0) {
            client.port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        client.send();
    }

    public void send() {
        System.out.println("Try to connet to " + serverIp + " via Port" + port);
        st = new SendThread(serverIp, port);
        st.start();
    }

    class SendThread extends Thread {
        private Socket soc;

        public SendThread(String theIp, int thePort) {
            try {
                soc = new Socket(theIp, thePort);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);          
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String toSend = "Hello ";
                    soc.getOutputStream().write(toSend.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(800);
                    System.out.println("sent");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);          
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run both Java files on the server pc, the connection works fine. It also worked if I set up a local Wi-Fi with one laptop and connect to it using another laptop.
But, when I run the client file from a laptop connected to the internet, I am not able to get a connection.
In the firewall on the Server, I opened a number of ports for the connection and the laptop I use as a client has the firewall disabled.
Apart from the firewall, I do not really know what to look into in order to get the connection running. Any ideas as to the cause of my problem and a solution?

Comment: Is the server behind NAT? Have you forwarded the right ports?

Comment: I don't think it is behind a NAT. If go to whatismyip.com I get the same address as when I enter ipconfig in the command window. Or is there anything else I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: The windows firewall was still blocking the ports for Java. It took me a little longer to figure this out, because I was not registered as admin on that pc and could not see the rules.